# Chrome Extension: JS DOM button click method is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, google-chrome-extension, click

From an extension I need to click a button but **click event is not triggered**, I tested the following JS DOM methods:

```
getElementsByClassName('button')[0].click(); // Not working
document.querySelector('button').click(); // Not working
```

The button is created on **React.js**, this can be the causes of the failed click event?

Any suggestion?

Comment: In both the cases you will get the dom in array. So take the index and then bind click event.  `getElementsByClassName('button')[0].click()` for all the buttons you need to a loop

Comment: Thank you for response. Can you please share any link regarding your suggested solution? Actually i'm new so i don't know much about bind. Thanks.

Comment: One thing to clear, I want to click the button of a website whose button created on React.js. Thanks

Comment: I have seen a post having solution of updating the props/state so it will happen. Is that possible and if then how? Thanks.

Comment: It probably means your code runs before the button is created. Wait for it using MutationObserver or setTimeout/setInterval. More info: [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: Click event is not running on website's console. Checkout the download button here https://www.canva.com/design?create&type=TACQ-jGq9fY&category=tACFat6uXco&schema=web-2

Answer (score 1):

If the button has the class `button` and you want to click it by its class. Then please follow this code.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
  for (let btn of buttons) {
    btn.click();
  }
}, 1000);
```

> I have added setTimeout in case you don't get in react function as the buttons as not been loaded into DOM. you can neglect it if not required.

Comment: in which button you want to trigger the click operation? please say me that particular button's class name

Comment: I tried with getElementsByClassName('button')[0].click(); but its not working.

Comment: Do a console.log and check `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('button'))`

Comment: That's the whole script
`document.getElementsByClassName("_1QoxDw Qkd66A n9zSJA ZTpOuQ FcXOnA GnpDIA zQlusQ uRvRjQ vAm98g fa9inA")[0].click();`

Comment: YES, that's why it is not working. Try to select the button using different selectors. Console.log it and check it then bind the click event.

Comment: also console.log() in browser console. It might not be loaded into DOM where you re checking so showing undefined. If that is the case then try with 
setTimeOut()

Comment: Unfortunately, there are two button and only those two are not showing anything even in console and i'm running console on browser console to see if its working. Thanks

Comment: try using 
`document.getElementsByTagName('button')`  now `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('button'))`

Comment: It might be the interaction gap. You might be searching for some other things but the interpretations show something different. Please try with the other solutions.